# Issue with two cursors on top of each other in Windows XP

Tags: css, cursor, windows-xp

I'm having an issue with cursors. I have a CSS class which I will refer to as a block, as it is simply a div with a height and a width. Using jQuery UI the block is resizable and draggable. When the cursor is near the edges the resize icon is shown and when in the center of the block a grabbing icon is displayed. The grabbing icon is retrieved using `cursor: url(...), default;` and this is where the issue happens. Using a virtual machine to test on different operating systems I get a strange behavior in Windows XP only - two icons are shown at the same time. It is the grabbing icon, along with the style the cursor had before entering the draggable area (see image).

[image: Cursor Error illustration]

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cruckie/t3T4u/1/) illustrates the problem (works fine, except on my virtual machine with Windows XP)

In this project I'm developing for Chrome only and is only concerned about the behavior in Chorme. It happens only using Window XP. I tried using the `-webkit-grab` which works fine, but it shows up black on one of the other operating systems (I don't remember which one), so that's not a good solution (unless you know of a way to avoid the black icon).

Any clue on what is going on? If some of you out there can't reproduce it on Windows XP, I'd really like to hear that as well.

Best regards

Comment: I think your problem might be Virtual-machine related. Try disabling the 'cursor shadow' in your virtual machine. You can find this setting here http://citrixblogger.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/cursorshadowoff.jpg?w=1200

Comment: This could be because of the guest additions (allowing you to have your mouse cursor between your host and guest). What are you using to mount your machine ?

Comment: @MiguelStevens It works on other operating systems on my virtual machine. @Brewal I don't have the option to turn off shadow. The checkbox isn't even there. I don't have double cursors as long as I don't use a custom cursor (using `cursor: url(...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a bug with the Virtual Machine software you're using rather than a bug in your development.  The Virtual Machine software is stacking your host cursor over the VM's cursor, hence the double graphic you're seeing.

I've just tested this for you to double-check.  You're all-clear!

If you want to be really sure, load up [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/examples/l/blstylescursorexamples.htm) and try hovering over the links in the example there.

As an aside (and not that it should effect you in this particular example): you should really apply `cursor` properties to the element directly rather than to the `:hover` selector.  The cursor will only display when you mouse-over that element anyway, but it removes any ambiguity for older browsers.

Thus, from your example:

```css
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: url(https://mail.google.com/mail/images/2/openhand.cur), default;
}
```

Comment: Thank for the reply @johnkavanagh. I thought it was the virtua machine software as well, but it works as it is supposed to with other operating systems, using virtual machines.
The `:hover` is a mistake. In my code it is like your example, but on `:active` I set a new cursor.
The link you sent works fine on the virtual machine with Windows XP, except the last one (custom one) - same problem as I described.
Thank you! Does that mean you tested my fiddle using Windows XP?

Comment: It was the virtual machine. Just a bit strange it works on the other ones. I tried to use teamviewer to remote control the virtual machine and the extra cursor wasn't shown. Thanks for the answer :)